# How to start Bitcoin-qt with Bitcoin Cash?

Tags: bitcoin-cash, bitcoin-qt-setup, ecash

First of all I do not trust online wallets so I download full blockchain with Bitcoin-ABC. Unfortunaly bitcoin-abc does not contain bitcoin-qt binary. So my question is it possible to start original Bitcoin-QT with bitcoin-abc?

if this is not possible, what is the other way to use my wallet under bitcoin-abc?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Bitcoin ABC `0.16.1` binaries for linux have a QT GUI:
https://download.bitcoinabc.org/0.16.1/linux/ - I have not checked the other platforms, but I assume they do too.

They kept the same binary names (`bitcoin-qt`, `bitcoind`, etc) when they forked [Bitcoin Core](https://github.com/bitcoin/bitcoin), which is a bit confusing because it is a seperate network with its own consensus rules.

The standard `bitcoin-qt` ([Bitcoin Core](https://github.com/bitcoin/bitcoin)) only works for bitcoin, not bcash.

Comment: I downloaded this package https://download.bitcoinabc.org/0.16.1/linux/bitcoin-abc-0.16.1-aarch64-linux-gnu.tar.gz and did not find bitcoin-qt inside bin folder. Can you submit this?

Comment: I downloaded another dist and found bitcoin-qt there